# Behaviour of an infinitely jointed pendulum

Tags: calculus, physics

as seen by some animations at (for example) the wikipedia page on [double pendulums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum), the behaviour of a a pendulum with a single joint is already somewhat 'complicated.' Some quick googling seems to imply that for more joints, the behaviour only gets weirder. My question is, say we have a sequence $P_1, P_2,\ldots, P_n \ldots$ of pendulums with joints at distances $q_i$ from the pivot. Does the behaviour of these pendulums converge to some reasonable behaviour as $n \to \infty$? For example, do I get behaviour closer and closer to that of pinning a string to a wall, holding it horizontally, and letting it fall?

Comment: Isn't an infinitely-jointed pendulum a string?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: No. A string has finitely many particles.

Comment: A real-world string not only has finitely many particles but is subject to the laws of quantum mechanics, not classical mechanics. So it is definitely not correct to model a string as an infinitely jointed pendulum.

Comment: Even if we have $100$ joints then the last two joints is still a double pendulum so even if the pendulum as a whole behaves 'nicely' these two joints will still behave chaotic.

Comment: The (idealized) hanging string is not so reasonable. Look up "The paradox of the hanging string".

Comment: @Winther: If, for example, my traditional pendulum $P_0$ has length $k$, and I define $P_{2n}$ by adding a joint at $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $P_{2n+1}$ by adding a joint at $k - \frac{1}{2^n}$, then I never have a 'last two joints' in this limiting process which I can guarantee will behave chaotically.